# Excluir sessão php ao fechar navegador

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Estou usando CodeIgniter para desenvolver um projeto que envolve uma área restrita.

Estou usando sessão para armazenar os dados do usuário que está logado.

Preciso que ao fechar o navegador, essas informações sejam excluidas, lembrando que estou usando sessões da versão 3.1.6 do CodeIgniter.

Exemplo de como criei as sessões:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('associated_hash', $userData[0]->hash);
```

Como estou fazendo a leitura da sessão:

```
public function index() {
    if (!isset($this->session->associated_hash) || empty($this->session->associated_hash)) {
        redirect('login');
    }
    ...
}
```

Como estou fazendo a exclusão da sessão ao fazer logou pelo botão:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('associated_hash');
```

Minha configuração no config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Edit com a verificação no construtor:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if (!isset($this->session->associated_hash) || empty($this->session->associated_hash)) {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Perguntas: Quando você manda excluir a sessão ela apaga e por consequência não entra nas páginas restritas ? e Quando você fecha o navegador ainda persiste a sessão, sim ou não? Tipo estou te perguntando porque é um problema local seu e estou tentando descobrir!?!?

Comment: 1. Isso, se eu excluir a sessão eu não consigo mais acessar.
2. Sim, se eu fechar, a sessão continua.

Comment: é alguma coisa local... é dificil reproduzir, digo isso porque o que tem que ser feito na documentação relata! e não tem outra opção...

Comment: Cheguei a conclusão que é um bug q acontece no Firefox do Ubuntu. Testei no Chrome no Ubuntu e no Chrome e no Firefox no Windows e ele deslogou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vai no arquivo `application/config/config.php`, procure `$config['sess_expiration']` e atribua o valor ***0***, como demostrado logo abaixo:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0; // para quando fechar o navegador a sessão expire
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

na sua descrição já explica isso, observe:

> 'sess_expiration'

```
|   The number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
|   Setting to 0 (zero) means expire when the browser is closed.
```

*tradução*

```
| O número de SEGUNDOS que você deseja que a sessão dure.
| A configuração para 0 (zero) significa expirar quando o navegador está fechado.
```

Comment: Fiz os testes aqui e não excluiu a sessão :/ Vou editar a pergunta pra mostrar minha configuração de sessõa (está igual a sua)

Comment: @BernardoKowacic sinceridade eu já fiz site com CodeIgniter e a configuração é essa mesmo, agora o que você está fazendo? porque, tem que fechar o navegador por completo não só a aba!!! entendeu

Comment: @BernardoKowacic inclusive isso está na documentação como foi explicado. Agora vai depender realmente o que está fazendo! tem como contar o passo a passo.

Comment: Então, basicamente, quando o usuário acessa o site, ele vai poder fazer login para acessar a área restrita, quando ele informa email e senha, eu crio a sessão usando: $this->session->set_userdata('associated_hash', $userData[0]->hash). Ao acessar a página restrita ele faz a verificação do hash na função que é executada ao carregar a página para ver se ele existe e se ele é válido, para isso uso: $this->session->associated_hash. Caso ele queira fazer logout eu uso: $this->session->unset_userdata('associated_hash').

Comment: Coloque o código na sua pergunta do dois métodos! @BernardoKowacic, inclusive o que faz a verificação se está logado ou não!

Comment: atualizei a pergunta com o código

Comment: @BernardoKowacic coloque aquele if no construtor da sua classe

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70558/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-bernardo-kowacic).